# Obtain bank routing id for an order ID in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need To obtain paid bank routing number of a specific order Id in WooCommerce for my add ones! But it's not in order array. please help :)

Something like this:

```
$Routing_id($Order_id)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found routing Id in Bank gateway! then save it in WordPress Post's meta (update_post_meta) keys. then retrieve it in other places (get_post_meta).